# Java/Android Thread pause error

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have a class that implements runnable with the run function.

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
  while(running)
  {
    // thread code goes here::
    threadCode();////
    // thread code ends here
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Now i am trying to pause the thread if something happens.
I tried to use wait() and notify() but it crashed the app, afterwards i came with idea to use the "running" boolean and set it to false as for pause, and then back to true to resume.
Unfortunately it still crashes the app.

It gives me fatal error on logcat.

"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Is there any working simple way to pause a thread? ;/
Thx

**EDIT:**
it's not about thread at all.
I found where it crashes.
It crashes on alert dialog
here is the code of it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
      builder1.setTitle("Game over!");
     builder1.setMessage("You survived "+secs+"."+msecs+ " seconds.");
     builder1.setCancelable(false);
     builder1.setPositiveButton("Replay",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
         {
            // intialStuff();
             dialog.cancel();
         }
     });
     builder1.setNegativeButton("Rage quit",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             dialog.cancel();
         }
     });

     AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
     alert11.show();
```

i try to run it on canvas class
maybe it cant work on canvas class?
C is context of main activity.

Comment: What does your logcat tell you?

Answer (score 0):

On Android Threads work differently as against on a regular java 'main' based program. Threads spanned from the UI thread should use a Looper for their own use else they fall back to the main UI thread's Looper. For your query calling Looper.prepare() from inside the run method, probably the fist line inside it would do. However from a long term scalability and correct approach perspective consider using a Loader or an AsynchTask.

Comment: the problem is not on thread, it's related to alertDialog, i edited the main question. ;o

Comment: post the logcat here or exception trace.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems, first was i set int value on the message of the AlertDialog which caused the crash.
The fix is:

```
setMessage("You survived "+Integer.toString(secs)+"."+Integer.toString(msecs)+" seconds.")
```

The second problem and the main, i had to use hander on the thread so the AlertDialog will not crash.

Second fix:
create handler.

```
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() 
{
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {
            //Go to thread function
            threadCode();
        }
};
```

call it from the run function:

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
  while(true)
  {
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        //handler
        if(running)
        threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```